# Oracle variable length in SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way to use variable length in SUBSTR based upon length of another column ?

For example:

```
    SUBSTR ( name, 1, length( select name from v$DATABASE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do:

```
SUBSTR(name, 1, (select length(d.name) from v$DATABASE d))
```

This is called a *scalar subquery*.  It needs to have its own parentheses, and can return at most one row (and in this context, at most one column).